# Cant save Report in formats other than .html in jasperviewer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using Netbeans 6.5 and for reports I'm using jasper reports. When I go to save the file in jasper viewer, it does not save it in a format other than `.html`. I.e. it does not save in `.pdf` or `.xls`.

Instead it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontMapper
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:121)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.GenerateReport(ReportUI.java:220)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(ReportUI.java:150)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI.access$100(ReportUI.java:37)
        at cbs.ui.ReportUI$2.actionPerformed(ReportUI.java:84)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

What might be the reason?

My report generation file:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * ReportUI.java
 *
 * Created on Jul 15, 2009, 12:02:13 AM
 */

package cbs.ui;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import controller.PopulateData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohanish Timble
 */
public class ReportUI extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public int SelectedContId;

    /** Creates new form ReportUI */
    public ReportUI() {
        initComponents();
        PopulateContractorCombo();
    }



    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmbContractor = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        btnGenerateBill = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Bill Generation Form");

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Contractor Name"));

        jLabel1.setText("Contractor Name:");

        cmbContractor.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "-------Select----------" }));
        cmbContractor.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbContractorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnGenerateBill.setText("Generate Bill");
        btnGenerateBill.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnGenerateBill, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btnCancel))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(cmbContractor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(151, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(cmbContractor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 65, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnCancel)
                    .addComponent(btnGenerateBill))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
PopulateData populateData = new PopulateData();

    private void btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnGenerateBillActionPerformed
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            GenerateReport();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnGenerateBillActionPerformed

    private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnCancelActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        cmbContractor.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnCancelActionPerformed

    private void cmbContractorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_cmbContractorActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String ContName=null;

        ContName=cmbContractor.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
        SelectedContId=populateData.getContIdCorrespondingToContName(ContName);
}//GEN-LAST:event_cmbContractorActionPerformed

    public void PopulateContractorCombo()
    {
        Vector<String> contractor=(Vector<String>)populateData.getContractorList();

        //cmbCustomer.removeAllItems();
        for(int i=0;i < contractor.size();i++){
            cmbContractor.addItem((String)contractor.get(i));

        }
    }

    public void GenerateReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, JRException, SQLException {
         String reportSource = "./report/templates/Contractor_Bill.jrxml";
            String reportDest = "./report/results/Contractor_Bill";
            java.sql.Connection conn = null;
            //String reportSource = "./report/templates/HelloReportWorld.jrxml";
            //String reportDest = "./report/results/HelloReportWorld.html";

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("contractorId",SelectedContId);
            params.put("Contractor Name",cmbContractor.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
            try
            {
                JasperReport jasperReport = null;
                        try {
                            //Class.forName("org.git.mm.mysql.jdbc.ClientDriver");
                            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
                            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

                            // Make the driver class available.


            // Create a connection to pass into the report.
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbs_new", "root", "mohanish");

            // Replace the empty JR datasource parameter with
            // the connection parameter named conn.


                        } catch (JRException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ReportUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                JasperPrint jasperPrint =JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,conn );


                JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest+".html");
                //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,reportDest+".pdf");


                JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);


                //JDialog jviewer = new JDialog();

               //JRViewer aViewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);

                //jviewer.setTitle("Bill Preview");
                //jviewer.setModal(true);
                //jviewer.getContentPane().add(aViewer);
               // jviewer.pack();

                //java.awt.Dimension diadim =java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
               // jviewer.setSize(diadim.width,diadim.height);
                //jviewer.requestFocus();
               // jviewer.show();
               // jviewer.setAlwaysOnTop(true);


            }

            catch (JRException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGenerateBill;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cmbContractor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables

}
```

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports uses [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) for pdf creation, you should add iText.jar to your classpath.